# Function to remove more than 2 consecutive repetitions of a string not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Here's my function:

```py
def remove_more_than_two_reps(text):
    result = list(text)
    for idx,char in enumerate(text):       
        if(result[:idx].count(char) > 2):
            result.remove(char) 
    return ''.join(result)
```

expected result:

```py
text = 'teeeexxxxt'
result = remove_more_than_two_reps(text)
>'teexxt'
```

My function just returns the original string, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `append` which is `O(1)` instead of `remove` which is `O(n)`:

```
def remove_more_than_two_reps(text: str) -> str:
    result = []
    for ch in text:
        if len(result) < 2 or result[-1] != ch or result[-2] != ch:
            result.append(ch)
    return ''.join(result)

text = 'teeeexxxxt'
result = remove_more_than_two_reps(text)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
teexxt
```

Comment: Tyvm, quite an elegant and simple solution

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to share an [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) solution, useful when you have particularly big strings (since it avoids allocating an enormous list):

```py
import itertools as it

def remove_more_than_two_reps(text: str) -> str:
    reps_of_at_most_two = (it.islice(reps, 2) for _, reps in it.groupby(text))
    return ''.join(it.chain.from_iterable(reps_of_at_most_two))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be using a pattern, matching 3 or more times the same character `(.)\1{2,}` and in the replacement use 2 times the captured group value:

```
import re

def remove_more_than_two_reps(text):
    return re.sub(r'(.)\1{2,}', r'\1\1', text)

text = 'teeeexxxxt'

print(remove_more_than_two_reps(text))
```

Output

```
teexxt
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0VZL5C/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/P5meVU).